# Meta tag-synonym request: [tags]->[tagging]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, meta

While [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) is synonymed to [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) is not synonymed yet. Could [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) be synonymed to [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging)?